# AngularJS : the binding isn't applied when calling a service on an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote this code to extract the problem I'm confronted with :

When I directly call `myService()` via the ng-click ("TEST 2" button), the value of `myObject.myProperty` is updated and binded (the view show the new value).

But when I add an event listener ("TEST 1" button), its value is updated but not binded. I can check that because of the "WHAT IS THE VALUE ?" which by the way suddenly apply the binding when I click on it.

Then I really don't get why the value is not binded in the case of the event listeners ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>

        <section ng-controller="MainController">
            {{ myObject.myProperty }} !

            <p>
                <button id="my-button">TEST 1</button>
                <button ng-click="callMyService()">TEST 2</button>
            </p>

            <p><button ng-click="whatIsTheValue()">WHAT IS THE VALUE ?</button></p>
        </section>

        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

            app.run(function($rootScope, $document, myService)
            {
                $rootScope.myObject = { myProperty: 'Run' };

                angular.element(document.getElementById('my-button')).bind('click', function(event)
                {
                    myService();
                });
            });

            app.service('myService', function($rootScope)
            {
                return function()
                {
                    console.log($rootScope.myObject.myProperty);

                    $rootScope.myObject.myProperty = 'Service';

                    console.log($rootScope.myObject.myProperty);
                };
            });

            app.controller('MainController', function($scope, myService, $interval)
            {
                $scope.myObject.myProperty = 'Controller';

                $scope.callMyService = function()
                {
                    myService();
                };

                $scope.whatIsTheValue = function()
                {
                    console.log($scope.myObject.myProperty);
                };
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `$rootScope.$apply()` after `myService()`

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('my-button')).bind('click', function(event)
{
    myService();
    $rootScope.$apply()
});
```

Comment: Using `ng-` events is the way to say angular that please update the related `binds` also, else you need to take care of that explicitly by using `$apply()`.

Comment: Yes. In ng events, Angular adds this to the end by default, though this may interest you: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: Yes the things is that I have to use that to use it inside Cordova when the back button is pressed and I have a watcher that changes the view when the current state is changed. This is quite interesting then :)